# Is there a way to span an ID multiple times in an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

Excuse me in advance if I am not using correct terminology, my understanding of programming is very basic. But essentially I am trying to write a program in HTML and Javascript that will automatically fill IDs in a form based on user input. My problem is that I can only print the ID once in the form, when I need it to print in multiple locations. Here is a snippet of the code that highlights my issue:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script language="JavaScript">
        
    function showInput(){       
        document.getElementById('@userVLAN').innerHTML = document.getElementById("!userVLAN").value;
        document.getElementById('@voiceVLAN').innerHTML = document.getElementById("!voiceVLAN").value;
        document.getElementById('@mgmtVLAN').innerHTML = document.getElementById("!mgmtVLAN").value;
        document.getElementById('@printerVLAN').innerHTML = document.getElementById("!printerVLAN").value;
    }
    </script>
    
    <FONT FACE="COURIER NEW" SIZE="2">
    <body>
    <form>
    <TABLE><TR>
    <TD align="right" style="height:20px">VLAN TAGS:</TD>
    <TD><input style="font-family:Courier New; font-size:12px;width:100px;height:15px" type="text" name="!userVLAN" placeholder="USER_VLAN ID" id="!userVLAN" oninput="userVLANfunction()"></TD>
    <TD><input style="font-family:Courier New; font-size:12px;width:100px;height:15px" type="text" name="!voiceVLAN" placeholder="VOICE_VLAN ID" id="!voiceVLAN" oninput="voiceVLANfunction()"></TD>
    <TD><input style="font-family:Courier New; font-size:12px;width:100px;height:15px" type="text" name="!mgmtVLAN" placeholder="MANAGEMENT_VLAN ID" id="!mgmtVLAN" oninput="mgmtVLANfunction()"></TD>
    <TD><input style="font-family:Courier New; font-size:12px;width:100px;height:15px" type="text" name="!printerVLAN" placeholder="PRINTER_VLAN ID" id="!printerVLAN" oninput="printerVLANfunction()"></TD>
    </TABLE>
    </form>
    
    <script>
    function userVLANfunction() {var x = document.getElementById("!userVLAN").value;document.getElementById('@userVLAN').innerHTML = x;}
    function voiceVLANfunction() {var x = document.getElementById("!voiceVLAN").value;document.getElementById('@voiceVLAN').innerHTML = x;}
    function mgmtVLANfunction() {var x = document.getElementById("!mgmtVLAN").value;document.getElementById('@mgmtVLAN').innerHTML = x;}
    function printerVLANfunction() {var x = document.getElementById("!printerVLAN").value;document.getElementById('@printerVLAN').innerHTML = x;}
    </script>
    
    vlan <span id='@userVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span><BR>
    name USER_VLAN<BR>
    vlan <span id='@voiceVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span><BR>
    name VOICE_VLANx<BR>
    vlan <span id='@mgmtVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span><BR>
    name MANAGEMENT_VLAN<BR>
    vlan <span id='@printerVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span><BR>
    name PRINTER_VLAN<BR>
    
    ip dhcp snooping vlan <span id='@userVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,<span id='@voiceVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,<span id='@mgmtVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,<span id='@printerVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span><BR>
    
    ip arp inspection vlan <span id='@userVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,<span id='@voiceVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,<span id='@mgmtVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,<span id='@printerVLAN' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span><BR>
    
    </FONT>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when the user enters the IDs into the textbox it fills the vlan but not the dhcp snooping or arp inspection. The currently workaround is to have the user enter the vlans into multiple textboxes and creating severally instances of every entry, but I would prefer to have the user only have to type it once. Thank you.

Comment: ID must be unique through page. You can always use data attributes or classes for selection

Answer (score 0):

You can use html `class` since html `id` must be unique.

Then you can use `for` to iterate through them.

To make things easier, you can use `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` to filter DOM element by their ID or class.

```
var x = document.querySelector("#yourid"); // filtering by ID
var x = document.querySelector(".yourclass"); // filtering by class (only first one is selected)
var arr = document.querySelector(".yourclass"); // filtering by class (all element of such class)
```

Here's an example edited from your code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script language="JavaScript">
    
function showInput(){       
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".show");
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].innerHTML = document.querySelector(".yourinput").value;
    }
}
</script>

<FONT FACE="COURIER NEW" SIZE="2">
<body>
<form>
<TABLE><TR>
<TD align="right" style="height:20px">VLAN TAGS:</TD>
<TD><input style="font-family:Courier New; font-size:12px;width:100px;height:15px" type="text" name="!userVLAN" placeholder="USER_VLAN ID" class='yourinput' oninput="showInput()"></TD>

</TABLE>
</form>

input: <span class='show' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span><BR>

ip dhcp snooping vlan 
<span class='show' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,
<span class='show' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,
<span class='show' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,
<span class='show' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span><BR>

ip arp inspection vlan 
<span class='show' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,
<span class='show' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,
<span class='show' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span>,
<span class='show' style="background-color: #00FF00"></span><BR>

</FONT>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this! This greatly simplified my code and works great, I appreciate it.